# Can't toggle audio/font awesome icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, local-storage, font-awesome

I'm pretty new to JS/jQuery, please forgive me if I've made an incredibly obtuse mistake! :)

```
var backgroundTrackObj        = document.createElement("audio");
    backgroundTrackObj.src    = "//tjone270.org/quakelive/2-24%20The%20Fiery%20Stronghold.mp3";
    backgroundTrackObj.volume = 0.1;
var playpauseButton           = $("#playpause_background");

function BackgroundTrack(nochange) {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var bgMusic = localStorage.getItem("bgMusic");
    if (bgMusic === "false") {
      backgroundTrackObj.pause();

      playpauseButton.removeClass("fa-pause");
      playpauseButton.addClass("fa-play");
      if (!nochange) {
        localStorage.setItem("bgMusic", "false");
      }
    } else if (bgMusic === "true" || bgMusic === null) {
      backgroundTrackObj.play();
      playpauseButton.removeClass("fa-play");
      playpauseButton.addClass("fa-pause");
      if (!nochange || bgMusic === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("bgMusic", "true");
      }
    }
  } else {
    backgroundTrackObj.play();
  }
}

BackgroundTrack(true);
```

This is my code. I'm loading it in as a file to the current page (via `<script src>`).

There's a clickable icon in my navbar:

```
<li><a class="navbar-brand" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;" onclick="BackgroundTrack(false)"><i id="playpause_background" class="fa"></i></a></li>
```

When the page loads, it runs `BackgroundTrack(true)`. I expect it to look at local storage for the `bgMusic` key, and if found with a "true" or "false" value, play or not play accordingly and change the clickable icon's icon to match the current state.

When I click the button, nothing happens, however if I manually set the local storage key, the music plays/not plays properly, but the button itself won't set the `bgMusic` key. The `BackgroundTrack(true)` will set the key to "true" if the key doesn't previously exist - but that's as much luck as I'm having with it at the moment.

I've manually tested the `.play()` and `.pause()` methods on the `backgroundTrackObj` var, and that works fine in the Chrome console. Using `.addClass` and `.removeClass` doesn't seem to work at all however.

Any ideas anyone?

UPDATE: https://jsfiddle.net/7qxrqk8q

Comment: Provide a live example in `jsfiddle` or SO Snippet.

Comment: Since it works fine in console, I think you have something wrong with this if 
' if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {'. 
I suggest you to remove everything from the function except add/remove Class logic and add functionality back piece by piece.

Comment: Added jsFiddle link @Mr.x

Comment: @Animus I thought that too, but it can't be as the `bgMusic` key is set in local storage, which means that execution continues beyond that point.

Comment: @ThomasJones
Sorry for not answering for too long. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJWzEO
This is what i mean. Also, better use cdn: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/

Comment: @Animus That's exactly the effect I'm after! I'm just not sure why my version doesn't work though, it's doing essentially the same thing, just with localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

There was a few things to change.

1. 1st of all, the click was assigned to icon, but not the button.
2. The other thing is you checked the state of the music parameter, based on local storage, starting from the 1st click. So that is why you wasn't able to change it.
3. And final, is that you checking Storage, but why not localStorage?

I've created button click with jQuery:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  musicState = !musicState;
    backgroundTrack(musicState);
});
```

Button id:

```
<button id="btn"><i id="playpause_background" class="fa"></i></button>
```

As well as variable for music play state:

```
musicState = false;
```

Function:

```
function backgroundTrack(el) {
 var bgMusic = localStorage.getItem("bgMusic");
  if(localStorage){
    if (el === false) {
      playpauseButton.removeClass("fa-pause");
      playpauseButton.addClass("fa-play");
      backgroundTrackObj.pause();
      if (!el) {
        localStorage.setItem("bgMusic", "false");
      }
    } else if ( (el === true) || (bgMusic === null) ){
      playpauseButton.removeClass("fa-play");
      playpauseButton.addClass("fa-pause");
      backgroundTrackObj.play();
      if (!el || bgMusic === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("bgMusic", "true");
      }
    }
   } else {
      backgroundTrackObj.play();
   }
}
```

Notify me if that was helpful.

[Check my solution here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrmEqK?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

I updated your BackgroundTrack function as below. The thing is that you need to distinguish between using the local storage and whether the button is being played or not. Both of them can have the same value but not all the time. This is what was making writing the function a bit tricky. The best you can get is to click twice at the pause button at the very beginning when you start the page, even it will not track the storage.

```
function BackgroundTrack(nochange) {
    if (typeof(Storage) === "undefined") {
        return backgroundTrackObj.play();
    }

    var bgMusic = localStorage.getItem("bgMusic"), update;
    var isPlay = nochange ? bgMusic === "true" : playpauseButton.hasClass("fa-play");

    if(isPlay){ //toggle
        playpauseButton.removeClass("fa-play");
        playpauseButton.addClass("fa-pause");
        backgroundTrackObj.play();
        update = "true";
    }else{
        playpauseButton.removeClass("fa-pause");
        playpauseButton.addClass("fa-play");
        backgroundTrackObj.pause();
        update = "false";
    }

    if (!nochange) {
        localStorage.setItem("bgMusic", update);
    }
}
```

```js
   var backgroundTrackObj        = document.createElement("audio");
    backgroundTrackObj.src    = "//tjone270.org/quakelive/2-24%20The%20Fiery%20Stronghold.mp3";
    backgroundTrackObj.volume = 0.1;
var playpauseButton           = $("#playpause_background");

function BackgroundTrack(nochange) {
 if (typeof(Storage) === "undefined") {
  return backgroundTrackObj.play();
 }
 
 var bgMusic = localStorage.getItem("bgMusic"), update;
 var isPlay = nochange ? bgMusic === "true" : playpauseButton.hasClass("fa-play");
 
 if(isPlay){ //toggle
  playpauseButton.removeClass("fa-play");
      playpauseButton.addClass("fa-pause");
      backgroundTrackObj.play();
       update = "true";
 }else{
      playpauseButton.removeClass("fa-pause");
       playpauseButton.addClass("fa-play");
       backgroundTrackObj.pause();
      update = "false";
 }
 
 if (!nochange) {
  localStorage.setItem("bgMusic", update);
 }
}

BackgroundTrack(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a0b5affde9.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="BackgroundTrack(false)"><i id="playpause_background" class="fa"></i></button>
</body>
</html>
```